# Getting an error when trying to install NUT

Tags: installation, ups

Im trying to install nut on a headless machine with ubuntu server 12.04 and I keep geeting this error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install nut
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nut is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up nut-server (2.6.3-1ubuntu1.1) ...
grep: /etc/nut/nut.conf: No such file or directory
sed: can't read /etc/nut/nut.conf: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing nut-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nut:
 nut depends on nut-server; however:
  Package nut-server is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing nut (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a          previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 nut-server
 nut
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple attempts to configure nut to work with my UPS I decided to uninstall everything and start from the beginning. During this uninstall process I somehow deleted nut.conf form /etc/nut. To be able to install nut again I had to manually create this file and enter `MODE=standalone` in it.